# facebook - Is it possible to prompt user for a require permission dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am developing a small facebook application.
In my application I need offline_access and email permission. I've been succesfully prompting the user for permission using

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,offline_access");
```

But what I really want to do is prompt the user with a **require** permission dialog, not **request**.

Does anyone know how to do that in javascript?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,offline_access", function(perms) {
   if (!perms) {
     document.location.href='YouNeedToAuthorize.html';
   } else {
     document.location.href='homePage.html';
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just deny his access if he doesn't accept it.